# Checking if two variables are empty

Tags: php

I'm trying to set up a couple of `elseif` statements to see if some input fields are empty or not. The values of those input fields are declared as $date1 and $date 2. If those fields are not empty, then a MySQL query will select all data that falls between those two dates.

Specifically, I'm having trouble with the condition. This is what I have so far:

```
$keyword = esc_sql($_GET['keyword']);
$date1 = esc_sql($_GET['date1']);
$date2 = esc_sql($_GET['date2']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ";

if(!empty($keyword)){
    $sql .= " name LIKE '%$keyword%'";
}

elseif(!empty($date1)){
    $sql .= " introDate = '$dateIntro1'";
}

elseif (!empty($date1) && !empty($date2)) {
    sql .= " introDate BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'"
}
```

However, the `elseif` condition doesn't seem to work, as when I add the SQL query, I do not get any results. I have already tested the SQL query and it works fine. What might I be missing?

Comment: I dont see you executing that query anywhere..

Comment: where are the $date1 & $date2 variables set

Comment: That's not valid PHP. You can't just put SQL in a PHP script. You need to do some research on how to use mysqli functions.

Comment: And you need an `if` for an `elseif`

Comment: *"What might I be missing?"* - Error checking and Lord only knows what you meant by `AND 'date2'`.

Comment: Too much code is missing here.

Comment: Sorry-- wrote this in a hurry last night. I've added the rest of the code for context and fixed typos. I also added the `if` condition-- I have a keyword input blank as well and that's what that is for.

Answer (score -2):

There is missing `$` before `date2`, update to:

```
 SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE date BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'
```

And of course you need to send the query to database, like [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) or whatever driver you use.

Also beware of SQL injection in case the variables come from user input. Rather generally use variable binding.